# Is there any other way to install Laravel or Yii without using the command prompt?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, laravel

Just need a little help here. Right now I am studying another framework. Before I am using CodeIgniter and Smarty as my development tools. But I decided to switch to another framework. My choices are Yii and Laravel.

I tried to install them without having an error and creating simple site. But is there another way to install this frameworks without using command prompt? Like in the CodeIgniter, they have a zip file and once you've extracted it you can start creating your site.

Comment: Umm, Yii needs just one time a command to create a web application. you can get a clone from newly created application, and reuse it later.

Comment: You mean after creating my Yii site using yiic tool I can reuse this?

Comment: I have done it and I had no problem with it. But the only important note is to check the index.php of your project to set appropriate path of yii's framework

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I am using my android phone to study this framework. I will try it. Thank you very much. And I will inform you once I'm done.

Comment: You're welcome dear ;)

Comment: Ok sir, it is already running. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve this issue by creating first my Yii app using yiic tool. After that I transffered the created folder into another directory and just edit the index.php and set the correct path for Yii framework.